# Chord detection in JavaScript based on String Array of notes

Tags: javascript, music-notation

I want to detect chords based on input String with notes (e.g. `'C'`, `'F'`, `'G'`) and get the resulting output chord (in this case, `'Csus4'`). I've done some research and it seems that all of the solutions out there are for working on audio stream input. Is there some JavaScript library that does this based on String input rather than an audio stream?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belong to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [danigb/tonal](https://github.com/danigb/tonal) library and the [Detect module](https://danigb.github.io/tonal/api/module-Detect.html) does exactly what I need:

```
import { chord } from 'tonal-detect'
chord(['C', 'F', 'G']) // => ['Csus4']
```

Comment: This is not actually accurate for a lot of cases.

Comment: it's now `Tonal.Chord.detect(['C', 'F', 'G'])` in the latest version (v4)